# Chat cliente Não é possível ler dados a partir da ligação de transporte:

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, tcpclient

Olá a todos é o seguinte eu fiz um server tc pque já conclui, no ultimos dias eu tenho andado a fazer o cliente mas está a dar o seguinte erro

> Não é possível ler dados a partir da ligação de transporte: Uma
>   operação de bloqueio foi interrompida por uma chamada a
>   WSACancelBlockingCall.

O erro está a dár nesta parte do código

```
     private void ReceiveMessages()
            {
                srReceiver = new StreamReader(tcpServer.GetStream());
                string ConResponse = srReceiver.ReadLine();
                if (ConResponse[0] == '1')
                {
                    this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { "Conected!" });
                }
                else
                {
                    string Reason = "Nao conectado: ";
                    Reason += ConResponse.Substring(2, ConResponse.Length - 2);
                    this.Invoke(new CloseConnectionCallback(this.CloseConnection), new object[] { Reason });

    return;
                }
                while (Connected)
                {

                    try
                    {

                        this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { srReceiver.ReadLine() });
                    }
                    catch
                    { }
                }
            }
```

**Update1**
é só para avisar que me estou a connectar com o ip 127.0.0.1 com a porta 1177